# Sending attachments with Mailgun using Powershell

Tags: powershell, email-attachments, mailgun

I cannot find any answer on Google or either Mailgun support on how to send attachments using Powershell. Sending mails without attachments works fine with Mailgun and Powershell. This is my code.

```
        $apikey = "key-1342323f7d35352fa4dda3af3ca10e"
        $idpass = "api:$($apikey)"
        $basicauth = [System.Convert]::ToBase64String([System.Text.Encoding]::ASCII.GetBytes($idpass))
        $headers = @{
            Authorization = "Basic $basicauth";
        }
        $url = "https://api.mailgun.net/v3/sandboxac77741768d442323b96495501ac24b.mailgun.org/messages"
        $mailbody = @{
            from = "Mailgun Sandbox <postmaster@sandboxac77741768d442323b96495501ac24b.mailgun.org>";
            to = "myadress@email.com";
            subject = "Testing mail";
            text = "Email body here";
            attachment = "D:\temp\logfile.txt"          
        }
        Invoke-RestMethod -Uri $url -Method Post -Headers $headers -Body $mailbody -ContentType "multipart/form-data"
```

This results in:
Invoke-RestMethod : The remote server returned an error: (400) Bad Request

Comment: If that's your actual api key, you may want to go ahead and revoke it immediately :-)

Comment: That is not my actual :)

Answer (score 3):

Special thanks to https://stackoverflow.com/users/213135/alex from whom I stole code.

```
function ConvertTo-MimeMultiPartBody {
    param([Parameter(Mandatory=$true)][string]$Boundary, [Parameter(Mandatory=$true)][hashtable]$Data)

    $body = "";
    $Data.GetEnumerator() |% {
        $name = $_.Key
        $value = $_.Value

        $body += "--$Boundary`r`n"
        $body += "Content-Disposition: form-data; name=`"$name`""
        if ($value -is [byte[]]) {
            $fileName = $Data['FileName']
            if(!$fileName) { $fileName = $name }
            $body += "; filename=`"$fileName`"`r`n"
            $body += 'Content-Type: application/octet-stream'
            $value = [System.Text.Encoding]::GetEncoding("ISO-8859-1").GetString($value)
        }
        $body += "`r`n`r`n" + $value + "`r`n"
    }
    return $body + "--$boundary--"
}

$emaildomain = "example.com"
$apikey = "key-xxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxx"
$url = "https://api.mailgun.net/v2/$($emaildomain)/messages"
$headers = @{
    Authorization = "Basic " + ([System.Convert]::ToBase64String([System.Text.Encoding]::ASCII.GetBytes("api:$($apikey)")))
}

$email_parms = @{
    from = "me@example.com";
    to = "you@example.com";
    subject = "My Test Email";
    text = 'Your email does not support HTML.';
    html = "Hello World!";
    filename = "example.pdf"
    attachment = ([IO.File]::ReadAllBytes("c:\example.pdf"));
}
$boundary = [guid]::NewGuid().ToString()
$body = ConvertTo-MimeMultiPartBody $boundary $email_parms
Invoke-RestMethod -Uri $url -Method Post -Headers $headers -Body $body -ContentType "multipart/form-data; boundary=$boundary"
```

Answer (score 0):

a slight addition to have multiple attachments, pushed it in a module:

**mailgun.psm1**

```
<#
    .SYNOPSIS
        Interface to the Mailgun API Module

    .DESCRIPTION
        Sends an e-mail through the Mailgun API see https://documentation.mailgun.com/en/latest/user_manual.html#sending-via-api
        Define your maildomain and API key in MailGun.psd1 and place inside the module folder

    .EXAMPLE
        $from = "from@stackoverflow.com"
        $to = "to1@stackoverflow.com", "another@stackoverflow.com"
        $bcc = "bcc1@stackoveflow.com", "bcc2@stackoverflow.com"
        $subject = "a mail with a subject"
        $html = "this <b>test with attachments</b> text<br/> And another interesting line <hr />"
        $attachments = @{
            "ExampleAttachment1.png" = 'c:\temp\whatapps.png'
            "AnotherExample.txt" = 'c:\temp\Msinfo.txt'
        }
        Send-MailgunEmail -from $from -to -bcc $bcc $to -subject $subject -htmlText $html -attachments $attachments
#>
$ModuleData = Import-PowerShellDataFile "$PSScriptRoot\MailGun.psd1"

function ConvertTo-MimeMultiPartBody {
    <#
        .SYNOPSIS
            Convert email content with multiple attachments to correct format
            with help from https://stackoverflow.com/questions/45463391/sending-attachments-with-mailgun-using-powershell
    #>
    param(
        [Parameter(Mandatory = $true)]
        [string]
        $Boundary,

        [Parameter(Mandatory = $true)]
        [hashtable]
        $Data
    )

    $lb = "`r`n"
    $body = ""
    $Data.GetEnumerator() | ForEach-Object {
        $body += "--{0}{1}Content-Disposition: form-data; name=`"" -f $Boundary, $lb
        if ($_.Value -is [byte[]]) {
            $body += "attachment`"; filename=`"{0}`"{1}Content-Type: application/octet-stream{2}{3}{4}" -f
            $_.Key, $lb, $lb, $lb, [System.Text.Encoding]::GetEncoding("ISO-8859-1").GetString($_.Value)
        }
        else {
            $body += "{0}`"{1}{2}{3}" -f $_.Key, $lb, $lb, $_.Value
        }
        $body += $lb
    }
    return "{0}{1}--{2}--" -f $lb, $body, $boundary
}

function Send-MailgunEmail() {
    <#
        .SYNOPSIS
            Sends an email through mailguns API
    #>
    param(
        # The From e-mail address
        [Parameter(Mandatory = $True)]
        [string] $from,
        # The To e-mail address (comma divided string)
        [Parameter(Mandatory = $True)]
        [array] $to,
        # The bcc e-mail adresses
        [Parameter(Mandatory = $False)]
        [array] $bcc,
        # the subject
        [Parameter(Mandatory = $False)]
        [string] $subject = 'Mail without subject',
        # the text in the Text part
        [Parameter(Mandatory = $False)]
        [string] $text = 'Mail does not support Non Html readers',
        # the text in the HTML part
        [Parameter(Mandatory = $False)]
        [string] $htmlText = '<html>no body content</html>',
        # Either pass as parameter or set in MailGun.psd1
        [Parameter(Mandatory = $False)]
        [string] $emaildomain = $ModuleData.PrivateData.mailgun_emaildomain,
        # the api key as found in the mailgun profile either pass or set in MailGun.psd1
        [Parameter(Mandatory = $False)]
        [string] $apikey = $ModuleData.PrivateData.mailgun_apikey,
        # a list of attachments
        [Parameter(Mandatory = $False)]
        [hashtable] $attachments
    )

    $data = @{
        from    = $from
        to      = $to -join ','
        subject = $subject
        text    = $text
        html    = "<html>$htmlText</html>"
    }
    if ($bcc) { $data.Add('bcc', [string]($bcc -join ',')) }
    foreach ($attachment in $attachments.GetEnumerator()) {
        $attachmentbytes = [IO.File]::ReadAllBytes($attachment.Value)
        $data.Add($attachment.Name, $attachmentbytes)
    }

    $url = "https://api.mailgun.net/v3/$($emaildomain)/messages"
    $headers = @{Authorization = "Basic " + [System.Convert]::ToBase64String([System.Text.Encoding]::ASCII.GetBytes("api:$($apikey)"))}
    $boundary = [guid]::NewGuid().ToString()
    $contenttype = "multipart/form-data; boundary=$boundary"
    $body = ConvertTo-MimeMultiPartBody -Boundary $boundary -Data $data

    return Invoke-RestMethod -Method Post -Uri $url -Headers $headers -Body $body -ContentType $contenttype
}

Export-ModuleMember -Function Send-MailgunEmail
```

**mailgun.psd1**

```
@{
    RootModule = 'MailGun.psd1'
    ModuleVersion = '1.0.0.0'
    GUID = 'e0383493-22b2-4838-8095-67c865ae46de'
    Author = 'edelwater'

    PrivateData = @{
        mailgun_emaildomain = 'EXAMPLE.COM'
        mailgun_apikey = 'key-123fdsdafgd9gf043dfgd03sdd'
    }
}
```

**testmailgunmodule.ps1**

```
Import-Module "$PSScriptRoot\.\Modules\MailGun.psm1" -Force
$from = "from@stackoverflow.com"
        $to = "to1@stackoverflow.com", "another@stackoverflow.com"
        $bcc = "bcc1@stackoveflow.com", "bcc2@stackoverflow.com"
        $subject = "a mail with a subject"
        $html = "this <b>test with attachments</b> text<br/> And another interesting line <hr />"
        $attachments = @{
            "ExampleAttachment1.png" = 'c:\temp\whatapps.png'
            "AnotherExample.txt" = 'c:\temp\Msinfo.txt'
        }


Send-MailgunEmail -from $from -to $to -subject $subject -htmlText $html -attachments $attachments
```